# ¿Cambiar URL de la página sin perder los comentarios de Facebook?

Tags: facebook, url

Me veo obligado a cambiar la URL de algunas páginas de mi sitio, pero el problema que tengo, es que si lo hago perdería los comentarios del `comment box` de Facebook.

¿Hay alguna manera de cambiar la URL y que los comentarios del `comment box` apunten a la nueva URL?

Este es el código del `comment box`:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_ES/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8&appId=93773124298xxxx";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://www.example.com/" data-numposts="5"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la [documentación de Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments?locale=es_LA#settings), el valor de `href`/`data-href` indica:

> La URL absoluta con la que se asociarán de forma permanente los comentarios que se publiquen en el plugin. Todas las historias que se compartan en Facebook sobre los comentarios que se publicaron con el plugin de comentarios tendrán un enlace a esta URL.

El valor por defecto (si lo dejas vacío) es el de la URL en la que te encuentras, pero si especificas una URL entonces será el de esa URL en concreto. Entonces lo que tendrías que hacer es guardar la URL vieja y asociarla de alguna manera con la nueva (p.e. en una base de datos). Y cuando generes el código de Facebook para los comentarios, poner el valor de la URL antigua.

Por ejemplo, vamos a partir de que la página original era así `http://misitio.com/blog.php?id=1234` y lo has cambiado para que se vea así: `http://misitio.com/blog/1234`. Entonces en el valor de `data-href` pondrás el valor de la página original en lugar de la nueva:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://misitio.com/blog.php?id=1234" data-numposts="5"></div>
```